# Is volume level encryption enough to satisfy compliance requirements?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, file-encryption

We are implement a cloud application and using nosql technology. We know there are quite a few compliance requirements out there require doing data encryption at rest. However, we would like to know is the volume level encryption enough to satisfy the compliance requirement or we need to do more even at the application level encryption since the application level encryption most cases can be quite challenge.

Looking forward to your reply! Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the compliance framework and especially the auditor and compliance level, but for PCI-DSS it is only enough it is not handled by the OS Login (I.e. If not transparent). http://blog.403labs.com/post/8402704243/disk-encryption-and-pci-requirement-341

Comment: Probably not. In the UK, for example, the ICO have ruled that just volume level encryption wasn't sufficient in some cases. Depends on what you're storing though.

Comment: What standard are you trying to meet?